# Haxe compiling to C++ and JS source

Tags: haxe

I am trying to write source code in one language and have it converted to both native c++ and JS source. Ideally the converted source should be human readable and resemble the original source as best it can. I was hoping haxe could solve this problem for me. So I code in haxescript and have it convert it to its corresponding C++ and JS source. However the examples I'm finding of haxe seems to create the final application for you. So with C++ it will use msbuild (or whatever compiler it finds) and creates the final exe for you from generated C++ code. Does haxe also create the c++ and JS source code for you to view or is it all done internally to haxe and not accessible? If it is accessible then is it possible to remove the building side of haxe so it simply creates the source code and stops?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you generate CPP all the intermediate files are generated and kept wherever you decide to generate your output (the path given using `-cpp pathToOutput`). The fact that you get an executable is probably because you are using the `-main` switch. That implies an entry point to your application but that is not really required and you can just pass to the command line a bunch of types that you want to have built in your output.

For JS it is very similar, a single JS file is generated and it only has an entry point if you used `-main`.

Regarding the other topic, does your Haxe code resembles the generated code the answer is yes, but ... some of the types (like `Enum` and `Abstract`) only exist in Haxe so they will generate code that functionally works but it might look quite different. Also Haxe has an always-on optimizer/analyzer that might mungle your code in unexpected ways (the analyzer can be disabled). I still find that it is not that difficult to figure out the Haxe source from the generated code. JS has support for source mapping which is really useful for debugging. So in the end, Haxe doesn't do anything to obfuscate your generated code but also doesn't do much to try to preserve it too strictly.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. That sounds like just what I need. If I use multiple haxe files will it combine it into one c++ and one JS source file or will I get multiple c++ files and multiple JS files that resemble the original multiple haxe files layout?

Comment: C++ generates a lot of files (I believe one per type + headers + build files), JS always generates just one file that will combine all of your types.

Comment: @codetemplar - you should note that the CPP output isn't a simple source output. It is built upon a runtime framework provided by the hxcpp library, much in the same way the JS output depends on a javascript runtime (provided by the browser.) So it builds the executable (which includes the runtime) because that's what most people will want -- the intermediate source format is only marginally useful.

Comment: So I couldn't take the generated cpp file and include it as is in a different C++ visual studio project and expect it to build with minimal effort?

Comment: @FrancoPonticelli, How can I apply compiler optimizations like O1 O2 O3 to the generated CPP code? thank you